# Perl, Best Practices: Empty Arguments handling inside subroutine, use of $_

Tags: perl, arguments, subroutine

I ran into following code example while was reading book "Perl Best Practices by Damian Conway":

```perl
    sub fix {
        my (@args) = @_ ? @_ : $_; # Default to fixing $_ if no args provided

        for my $arg (@args) {
            print $arg;
        }

        return;
    }
```

Could you please help me to understand what exactly author wants to accomplish in this part of code?

```perl
my (@args) = @_ ? @_ : $_; # Default to fixing $_ if no args provided
```

I understand what "if" does, and it's clear for me that we will assign `$_` to "@args" when user does not provide parameters for "fix() sub"

But it's not clear what is the benefit to assign `$_` to @args since `$_` is undef, right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's important to take Perl Best Practices with a grain of salt, it is quite outdated and many of its ideas have turned out to be detrimental in the long run.

Comment: Could you please suggest where is the best place to search for most fresh Perl'ss 'best practices' guides?

Comment: I don't know of any books as such, but some of the practices I and others from the IRC community follow/recommend are encoded in [Perl::Critic::Freenode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Freenode).

Comment: [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/) is another good bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@_` and `$_` are two different variables, so `$_` can be defined even if `@_` is empty. `$_` is used as the default in many functions, e.g. [length](http://p3rl.org/length) or [chr](http://p3rl.org/chr).

See [$_](https://perldoc.pl/perlvar#$ARG) and [@_](https://perldoc.pl/perlvar#@ARG).

Comment: Second link "char" gives "Not Found" page

Comment: note that most builtins that use `$_` as the default argument only take a single argument.  Damian's suggestion of a sub that either takes a LIST or defaults to `$_` is a lousy idea, since you can't pass an array without worrying that it might be empty and result in `$_` being used.

Comment: @ysth even more complicated than that: most functions which use $_ as the default argument do so via either a parser special case or the `_` prototype, which coerces its first argument to scalar context. *Even if it's an array.* So normally `$_` is not even used unless no arguments are provided to the parser, which is of course impossible to determine other than via such a prototype.